# (Python) Using modulo to get the remainder from changing secs, to hrs and minutes

Tags: python, modulo

I'm currently new to learning python and stumbled upon this problem:

> Exercise 2-7 Get the Time
>   Write an algorithm that reads the amount of time in seconds and then displays the equivalent
>   hours, minutes and remaining seconds.
>   • One hour corresponds to 60 minutes.
>   • One minute corresponds to 60 seconds.

Here's how I wrote it:

```
def amount_time(t):
  h = t//3600
  m = int((t/3600 - h)*60)
  s = int(((t/3600 - h)*60 - m)*60)
  print("Number of hours:",h)
  print("Number of minutes:",m)
  print("Number of Seconds:", s)
amount_time(5000)
```

I was told there was an easier way to write it using modulo to get the remainder for the minutes and seconds, could someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just "out of my head", because I got no testing system I could use right now.

```
def amount_time(t):
    print("Number of Seconds:", t % 60)
    print("Number of Minutes:", (t // 60) % 60)
    print("Number of Hours:", (t // 3600))
```

What "t % 60" does:

1. take t, divide it by 60
2. remove everthing left of the dot
3. multiply with 60

With numbers:

1. 5000 / 60 = 83.33333
2. => 0.33333
3. 0.33333 * 60 = 20

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of minuts doesnt work correct, you use Modulo with the hours.
You could do the same with minutes as you did wirh seconds instead:

```
m =     (t - h * 3600) // 60
s = int (t - h*3600 - m*60)
ms = int ((t - h*3600 - m*60 - s) * 1000) # milliseconds
```

and to build the result string there are better ways, f.e.

```
print '{}:{}:{}.{}'.format(h,m,s,ms)
```

You find more ways and options to Format, if you look here:

[python dokumentation for string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Comment: My bad I forgot to change the mins back after I was done testing (edited it), integer division seems to work fine with the hrs, can't I use modulo with the minutes and seconds to shorten the number of operations?