# How Can I Limit Clock Counter to Two Digit and Turn over at 60 as an example - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

My issue is, though I can get the `milliSeconds` to rollover at `99`, the `minutes` continue to increment past `60` and `hours` past `24` - as shown below. I would like to correct the `minute` and `hour` count more importantly as the script will not run past two days.

format should be `dd : hh: mm : ml`

however I goes over the two digit  `01:25:1556:99`

Here is the Class Definition:

```
class StopWatch(Frame):
# Initialize the Main Function of the Stopwatch
def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
    self.startTime = 0.0
    self.nextTime = 0.0
    self.onRunning = 0
    self.timestr = StringVar()
    self.MakeWidget()

def Updater(self):
    self.nextTime = time.time() - self.startTime
    self.SetTime(self.nextTime)
    self.timer = self.after(50, self.Updater)

def SetTime(self, nextElap):
    days = int(nextElap  / 60 /60 / 24.0)
    hours = int(nextElap / 60 / 60.0 )
    minutes = int((nextElap / 60.0 )
    seconds = int(nextElap - minutes * 60.0)
    miliSeconds = int((nextElap - minutes * 60.0 - seconds) * 100)
    self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d' % (days, hours, minutes, seconds, miliSeconds))

   def Start(self):
    if not self.onRunning:
        self.startTime = time.time() - self.nextTime
        self.Updater()
        self.onRunning = 1
```

Comment: You can use the modulo `%` operator.

Comment: Look into the `datetime` package; you'll find a lot of useful formatting and conversion methods there.

Comment: Temporal stuff is hard. Unless this is homework or similar it is a bad idea to try and reinvent anything to do with dates and times when there are existing tools out there that have been debugged over many years.

Comment: As @solarc points out, the issue is that if `minutes` goes over 60, you want to keep it contained in `0..59`, right? so `minutes=60` should become `minutes=0`, `minutes=61` should be `minutes=1` and so on... And who does that? The modulo operator (`minutes % 60`) Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084887/python-using-modulo-to-get-the-remainder-from-changing-secs-to-hrs-and-minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neatest way to solve this problem is using the `divmod` function:

```
def SetTime(self, nextElap):
    days, nextElap = divmod(nextElap, 60*60*24)
    hours, nextElap = divmod(nextElap, 60*60)
    minutes, nextElap = divmod(nextElap, 60)
    seconds, nextElap = divmod(nextElap, 1)
    miliSeconds = int(nextElap * 1000)
    self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d' % (days, hours, minutes, seconds, miliSeconds))
```

Comment: Thx however it did not like - as per error 'seconds, nextElap = divmod... Specifically 'seconds' as Invalid Syntax